# ¿Por qué mi numero random siempre devuelve 0? (C++)

Tags: c++

Tengo este código que simula una reserva de boletos de avión, pero debo hacer que una función random reserve algunos asientos antes que el usuario los pueda escribir. Primero el numero cambiaba pero luego no supe que moví al tratar de trabajar el código y ahora solo me da cero como random.

````
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c = 1, fila, columna,columnar;
    int asiento[2][10] = {0};

    srand (time(NULL));
    columnar = rand () % 40 + 1;

    cout<<columna<<endl;

    cout<<"¡Bienvenido! A continuación realizarás tu reserva de boletos"<<endl;

    while( c <= 40){

        cout << "Favor ingresar el numero de fila (1-2)"<<endl;
        cin >> fila;
        cout << "Favor ingresar el numero de columna(1-40)"<<endl;
        cin >> columna;

        if(columna=columnar){
            cout<<"¡Asiento ocupado!";
        }

        if(asiento[fila - 1][columna - 1] == 0){
            asiento[fila - 1][columna - 1] = 1;
            c = c +1;
            cout << "¡Reserva exitosa!";
        }else
        cout << "¡Asiento ocupado!";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
        cout << asiento[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable a la que estas asignando el número random es `columnar` y la que (creo estas imprimiendo y dices que te da 0) es `columna`.

### Tienes actualmente:

```
columnar = rand () % 40 + 1; //Asignación del número random
cout << columna << endl; //Donde creo dices que te imprime 0
```

### Debería ser:

```
columnar = rand () % 40 + 1; //Asignación del número random
cout << columnar << endl; //Donde imprimirá el número random que generaste
```

Aparte en el `if` donde comparas el random con la variable `columna` hace falta un signo `=` para que pueda hacer la comparación correctamente.

### Tienes actualmente:

```
if(columna = columnar){
cout<<"¡Asiento ocupado!";
}
```

### Debería ser:

```
if(columna == columnar){
    cout<<"¡Asiento ocupado!";
    goto Inicio;
}
```

Finalmente te recomiendo pongas una sentencia `goto` en el condicional dónde comparas `columna` con `columnar` ya que si quieres evitar que siga con el procedimiento el usuario, el `if` solo imprimirá el mensaje de asiento ocupado, pero dejará seguir el proceso.

Ejemplo:

```
while( c <= 40){
        Inicio: // **NUEVO**
        cout << "Favor ingresar el numero de fila (1-2)"<<endl;
        cin >> fila;
        cout << "Favor ingresar el numero de columna(1-40)"<<endl;
        cin >> columna;

        if(columna==columnar){
            cout<<"¡Asiento ocupado!"<<endl;
            goto Inicio; // **NUEVO**
        }
//Continuan las demás lineas del programa...
```

Te dejo una breve documentación de Microsoft sobre la sentencia [`goto`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/goto-statement-cpp?view=vs-2019)